# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (wresult="<trust:RequestSecuri...")

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wif, single-sign-on

I am also getting a request validation error when using WIF.  I get correctly sent to the STS, but on the way back, I get this validation error.

I followed all the instructions.

```
<httpRuntime  requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

check!

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
```

check!

```
<pages validateRequest="false" >
```

check!

I tried a custom validator, but it never gets instantiated.

Error stack:

```
[HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (wresult="trust:RequestSecuri...").]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) +11396740
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateNameValueCollection(NameValueCollection nvc, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) +82
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +212
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.IsSignInResponse(HttpRequest request) +26
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.CanReadSignInResponse(HttpRequest request, Boolean onPage) +145
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args) +108
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +270
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A better way is to add a specific validator, as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443563/potentially-dangerous-request-form-in-wsfederationauthenticationmodule-issigninre/5446288#5446288).

Comment: A proper way of dealing with this is described [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443563/potentially-dangerous-request-form-in-wsfederationauthenticationmodule-issigninre/5446288#5446288

Comment: @Eugenio Yes, that's what I said. :-)

Comment: you are right :-). Missed the comment.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

after this add

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages validateRequest="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

also in mvc3 there is an AllowHtml attribute

```
[AllowHtml]
public string Property{ get; set; }
```

here are some useful links

[ASP.NET MVC – pages validateRequest=false doesn’t work?](http://jwwishart.wordpress.com/2009/06/22/asp-net-mvc-pages-validaterequestfalse-doesnt-work/)

[Why is ValidateInput(False) not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807662/why-is-validateinputfalse-not-working)

Comment: Sorry, edited to note that I do have pages validateRequest = false.

Comment: The AllowHtml attribute worked for me when this problem arose.

Comment: Using Web Forms, What happen's if I didn't want to turn of request validation for the entire site? 

MVC has a nice way to allow this for an object property, what about Web Forms.

Comment: @JasonFoglia this post may help resolve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/8017318/413670

Answer (score 3):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15250479/176357) if you are running .NET 4.5 which takes advantage of an updated request validator built in to ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You can put both constructs together in the system.web section as per [ASP.NET : A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2011/06/aspnet-potentially-dangerous.html).

Note that this is standard ASP.NET functionality. It is not connected to WIF.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC 3 (not sure about 2) you can add a global filter in global.asax.cs e.g.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new ValidateInputAttribute(false));
}
```

That coupled with the following should allow all data in and display it correctly and safely I think:

```
<httpRuntime encoderType="Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXssEncoder, AntiXssLibrary"/>
```

in web.config and using (note colon):

```
<%: Model.Something %>
```

or in Razor:

```
@Model.Something
```

and in some cases in Javascript:

```
@Html.Raw(Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.Something))
```